# Do not hide Android menu

Tags: android, menu

When an option menu is visible, any user action will hide it. How to prevent menu from being hidden as a result of any onTouchEvent outside menu borders ?

Comment: Why do you need this? This would break your users experience.

Comment: I have another [navigation] panel, it apears with menu together, so I'd like to be able to deal with it. However may be it isn't the best realization of such a fuctionality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

setGroupVisible(int group, boolean visible)
Show or hide all menu items that are in the given group.

or

setVisible(boolean visible)
Sets the visibility of the menu item.

Anyway, I think don't get exactly what you mean with menu, if this doesn't help comment and I'll give you more clues.

Comment: With menu i meant a panel, which apears when Menu button was pressed =) And your advise concerns only menu items, not the whole panel, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can try hiding all the items and see if it behaves the way you want (I am not sure, I haven't ever tried to hide all of them). I am not even sure this can be done :S